# _GET en bucle infinito PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un gestor de consultas en php al que llamo desde AJAX con Jquery con un GET asyncrono, este gestor se encarga de llamar a la función pertinente.

Una de estas funciones debe ejecutar un proceso que depende del número de registros que se han insertado hasta determinada fecha. Si el numero de registros es pequeño el proceso finaliza, realiza el echo, ajax obtiene el resultado y todo funciona correctamente, pero si el proceso es largo este finaliza (tengo un log que guarda el json de respuesta y este es correcto) pero parece que el echo no se realice, desde Ajax no se obtiene ninguna respuesta e inmediatamente vuelve a comenzar todo el proceso como si se realizase una nueva llamada _GET al gestor con los mismos parámetros.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8", true);
switch(mb_strtoupper($_GET['funcion'])){
[...]
}

$json = json_encode($respuesta);
Log::insertaLog('Gestor Consulta > Respuesta ' . $json);
// En ambos casos siempre se está guardando el registro del json y este es correcto, pero el _GET 
echo($json); flush();
```

La llamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", async: true, url: "/Code/Herramientas/GestorConsultas.php", dataType: "json", data: parametros, success: function (datos) { console.log(datos); }, error: function (peticion, mensaje) { console.log("Error invocacio: /Code/Herramientas/GestorConsultas.php " + parametros + " " + peticion + " " + mensaje); GNR_GestionaError(arguments.callee.name, mensaje); } })
```

Agradeceré cualquier ayuda.

**Editado**

Si ejecuto la llamada a la función sin pasar por el gestor se ejecuta correctamente siempre.

Comment: ¿Existirá tal vez un `timeout` en la ejecución desde Ajax?

Comment: Hola @quinqui, gracias por tu respuesta. Ni desde chrome ni firefox me devuelve ningún timeout. De hecho hasta que no mato el proceso php no se devuelve ningún mensaje. :(

Comment: Podés mostrar el código del switch o `Log::insertaLog()`? Aparentemente el cuello de botella se produce allí y tal vez haya algo que pueda mejorarse.

Comment: Hola @CJNimes,
El switch para esa función es:
    switch(mb_strtoupper($_GET['funcion'])) { 
    case 'PRCS_CNT_NWS': 
    if(validaArgumentos(array('nombreLista'))){
    $respuesta = prcsCntNwsSincroniza(); break;} // Re-Sincronización de la lista. }

El Log::insertaLog es simplemente un file_put_contents($nombreFichero, $datos, $crearFichero ? LOCK_EX : FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Lo que más me extraña es que para pocos registros sí finaliza bien, es cuando hay muchos cuando entra en bucle.

Comment: ¿El log de errores de PHP no dice nada al respecto? Sería **muy interesante** que pudieras revisarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy intentando configurarlo ya que no lo tenía bien pero tampoco me salta ningún error. 
Como decía, el Log inserta correctamente el json de salida (que simplemente es un contador del número de registros tratados) pero el echo parece no funcionar y el panel de inspección de chrome no registra ninguna respuesta. He tratado añadiendo un exit al final del proceso pero nada. Desesperado estoy ya.

Answer (score 1):

Si el problema surge cuando son varios registros, probablemente estás llegando al límite de memoria o al tiempo máximo de ejecución. Estos valores los podés modificar con un archivo `.htaccess` o con la función `ini_set()` de php.

**htaccess:**

```
php_value memory_limit 256M          # la letra indica la unidad de memoria: Megabyte, Gigabyte...
php_value max_execution_time 300     # tiempo en segundos
```

**ini_set:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Peeeeerooooo, antes de hacer esto recomendaría revisar cada uno de los procesos que estás ejecutando. Probá activando que se muestren todos los errores de PHP:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: Lo pensé, pero el proceso sí finaliza, el error en sí es que el ajax no recibe la respuesta por lo que algo me hace pensar que es un tema del _GET. 

Si se llama la función prcsCntNwsSincroniza() desde una página sin pasar por el gestor el _POST finaliza con un timeout pero solo se ejecuta una vez. :(

Comment: Agregá el código de ` prcsCntNwsSincroniza()` en tu pregunta, a ver si hay algo allì...